# Android Studio Socket.io disconnecting and reconnecting every few seconds

Tags: java, android-studio, flask, socket.io

I have a setup right now where I am running a flask server that handles websocket communication between and android phone and a raspberry pi node.js socket.io client. The android socket.io can connect to the flask server, the node.js client can connect, and I can emit messages between all 3, however my android studio socket.io client is disconnecting every 5-10 seconds and reconnecting. It continues to do this even when I leave the activity that causes it to connect, it will connect and disconnect from the server continuously. Here is the Java code in android studio:

```
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


public class ControlPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button greenButton;
    Button redButton;
    private Socket mSocket; {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.2:5000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    }
    //private EditText mInputMessageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_control_page);
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButtonGreen);
        greenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attemptSendGreen();
            }
        });
        redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButtonRed);
        redButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attemptSendRed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Server side in my flask code I have:

```
import flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import request
import json

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
clients = {}
sessions = {}

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "<h1> Hello World! </h1>"
    
@socketio.on('connect')
def testConnect():
    print('connected')
    emit('connected')

    
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def testDisconnect():
    userSID = request.sid
    print('disconnected ' + str(userSID))
    UserID = sessions[str(userSID)][0]
    UserType = sessions[str(userSID)][1]
    clients[UserID][UserType]=''
    sessions.pop(str(userSID))
        
@socketio.on('config')
def handle_config(data):
    print('received message: ' + str(data)+ str(type(data)))
    userSID = request.sid
    if type(data) == str:
        jsonData = eval(data)
    else:
        jsonData = data
    print(userSID)
    if jsonData['USER_KEY'] in clients:
        clients[jsonData['USER_KEY']][jsonData['USER_TYPE']]=userSID
    else:
        clients[jsonData['USER_KEY']] = {'USER':'',
                                     'HARDWARE':''}
        clients[jsonData['USER_KEY']][jsonData['USER_TYPE']]=userSID
    sessions[str(userSID)] = [jsonData['USER_KEY'], jsonData['USER_TYPE']]

@socketio.on('transfer')
def transfer(data):
    jsonData = eval(data)
    print(jsonData)
    UserID = jsonData['USER_KEY']
    UserType = jsonData['USER_TYPE']
    color = jsonData['MESSAGE']
    #message = data['MESSAGE']
    message = {'COLOR': color,
               'STATE': 1
        }
    jsonMessage = json.dumps(message)
    
    if UserType == 'USER':
        transferID = clients[UserID]['HARDWARE']
    else: 
        transferID = clients[UserID]['USER']
    emit('serverTransfer', jsonMessage, to=transferID)

socketio.run(app,host='192.168.1.2',port='5000') #remove this line when using gunicorn deployment
```

Everything server side is working fine with my node.js client, so I don't think that the problem is coming from the server.

This is the information I get back from my server that shows the android client disconnecting and reconnecting every few seconds:

```
WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
 * Serving Flask app "websocketTest" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://192.168.1.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:23] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:23] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=mO35rQ0Mi_5ZxYFXAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:23] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=mO35rQ0Mi_5ZxYFXAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:23] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=mO35rQ0Mi_5ZxYFXAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
connected
received message: { "USER_KEY": "TEST_USER", "MESSAGE": "asdfasdfasdf", "USER_TYPE":"USER"}<class 'str'>
6pKGg55-qcP9rejgAAAB
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:33] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=mO35rQ0Mi_5ZxYFXAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:33] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=mO35rQ0Mi_5ZxYFXAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
disconnected6pKGg55-qcP9rejgAAAB
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:33] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidCS&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:34] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidEm&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:34] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidEx&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:34] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidFW&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:34] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidFx&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
connected
received message: {'USER_KEY': 'TEST_USER', 'USER_TYPE': 'HARDWARE'}<class 'dict'>
1nrEBb6Xny3dpELEAAAD
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:35] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:35] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:35] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
connected
received message: { "USER_KEY": "TEST_USER", "MESSAGE": "asdfasdfasdf", "USER_TYPE":"USER"}<class 'str'>
85Gy1EZr-XWm32-6AAAF
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:39] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:39] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdidFj&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'USER_KEY': 'TEST_USER', 'MESSAGE': 'GREEN', 'USER_TYPE': 'USER'}
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdieaT&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:40] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'USER_KEY': 'TEST_USER', 'MESSAGE': 'GREEN', 'USER_TYPE': 'USER'}
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:41] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:41] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdiejT&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'USER_KEY': 'TEST_USER', 'MESSAGE': 'RED', 'USER_TYPE': 'USER'}
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:42] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:42] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdif2X&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'USER_KEY': 'TEST_USER', 'MESSAGE': 'RED', 'USER_TYPE': 'USER'}
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:45] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:45] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Vo6Qo1Suk5U6dnG0AAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
disconnected85Gy1EZr-XWm32-6AAAF
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:47] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Axb2tK8BaYqGqrgGAAAG HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Axb2tK8BaYqGqrgGAAAG HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:47] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Axb2tK8BaYqGqrgGAAAG HTTP/1.1" 200 -
connected
received message: { "USER_KEY": "TEST_USER", "MESSAGE": "asdfasdfasdf", "USER_TYPE":"USER"}<class 'str'>
RLGgcjYRr3G8437zAAAH
192.168.1.6 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:15:58] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZdifE4&b64=1&sid=6pJ6UIkNrvOanjMwAAAC HTTP/1.1" 200 -
disconnected1nrEBb6Xny3dpELEAAAD
192.168.1.5 - - [18/Apr/2021 18:16:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=Axb2tK8BaYqGqrgGAAAG HTTP/1.1" 200 -
disconnectedRLGgcjYRr3G8437zAAAH
```

The library I'm using to handle my socket.io in Java is imported as:

```
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

Any insight into what is causing my android client to disconnect would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
This problem goes away when I run my server in its deployed state in the Nginx, gunicorn, flask stack on port 80. The problem only persists when running flask directly on port 5000.

Comment: Did you solve it please?

Comment: Yes, have a look at my answer. @gaohomway

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but if that can help someone.

I think you was in polling mode.

Mechanism from the doc :
https://socket.io/docs/v3/how-it-works/#upgrade-mechanism

You have to set the transport mode : (in Kotlin)

```
val opts = IO.Options()
opts.transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
socket = IO.socket("url", opts)
```

WebSocket.NAME mean "websocket"

Comment: It does not work when you use https server

Comment: Https  or http have nothing to do with socket configuration to my mind. Both are working to me without changing socket's options.

Comment: I tried to use Polling and socket io disconnects and reconnects automatically

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck here, for a very long time I finally figured it out for whoever ends up to this post. The socket.io disconnections/reconnections are happening because of incomplete nginx.config file. To successfully proxy WebSocket connections, you need to configure Nginx appropriately.

`proxy_http_version 1.1;`: This directive ensures that Nginx uses HTTP/1.1, which is required for WebSocket connections.

`proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;`: This line tells Nginx to enable the WebSocket protocol upgrade when requested by the client.

`proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";`: This line specifies that the "Connection" header should be set to "upgrade" for WebSocket connections.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  # Enable HTTP/1.1
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  # Enable WebSocket
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  # Enable WebSocket
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```